# How to auto switch the rererence between different Oracle versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oracle, dll

I'm using a C# project that is linked to the OracleDataAccess.dll - V9 or V10, but only one of them at a time. My development machine has both installations. On the deployment machines only one of them is available. For this reason, I have to switch the reference betwenn V9 and V10 in my project dependent on the deployment machine.

Is it possible to automate this switching process? (May be by using #defines, pre-build commands, or alternate configuration settings) The only alternative I know is to use two different project files.

Comment: Why do you need to switch .dll at all? I think V9 dll + V9 Oracle client libs will work with Oracle 10 as well, unless you use new features of Oracle 10, of course.

Comment: I have no trouble with the version of the oracale database itself, but with the driver dlls for Oracle (Orcale client instalation).


If I link my software with the Oracle9 drivers and try to run it on a machine with Oracle10 drivers only, than I get an exception like this: can't locate OraOps9.dll. A simple copy of Oracle.DataAccess.dll and OraOps9.dll into the programms folder won't fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand if you build your product on the deployment machine but if not my suggestion is to detect the version of the OracleDataAccess.dll at install time and create an appconfig that contains the appropriate version using the assemblyBinding element.

Comment: Hi alex, did you check my proposal? If it helped you please mark it as an answer. Thanks in advance.